# From ListActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, listactivity

How can convert following code to fragment. i'm having trouble converting it to Fragment instead of "ListActivity". i have swipe tabs and on one of the tabs i would like below code, but the only issue is that it has to fragment.

```
public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
        R.color.green_light, R.color.orange_light,
        R.color.blue_light, R.color.red_light };

    private class MyPinnedSectionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements PinnedSectionListAdapter {

        public MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Item> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            view.setTag("" + position);
            if (getItem(position).type == Item.SECTION) {
                //view.setOnClickListener(PinnedSectionListActivity.this);
                view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[position % COLORS.length]));
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).type;
        }

        @Override public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
            return viewType == Item.SECTION;
        }
    }

    private static class Item {
        public static final int ITEM = 0;
        public static final int SECTION = 1;

        public final int type;
        public final String text;

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyPinnedSectionListAdapter adapter = new MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, prepareItems());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Item> prepareItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            result.add(new Item(Item.SECTION, "Section " + i));
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                result.add(new Item(Item.ITEM, "Item " + j));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

MY Try on onCreateView method:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false); MyPinnedSectionListAdapter adapter = new MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, prepareItems()); setListAdapter(adapter); 
return v; 
} 
private void setListAdapter(MyPinnedSectionListAdapter adapter) {
 }
```

Comment: where is your `PinnedSectionListActivity ` `onCreate` code?

Comment: I'm sorry i have now added to original question? i need help convert onCreate method to Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is not Activity, but can be contain in a FragmentActivity.

Build a Fragment, instantiated in a FragmentActivity.
Then use `Fragment.onCreateView()` method to inflate the layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm kind of new in android world. I actually need help with onCreateView. Please take a look at original question i have added my Try on onCreateView. i'm not getting any list as a output.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener
{
  /*rest of the code*/
}
```

Comment: How can i make it to just Fragment not by extending ListFragment. And i'm kind of stuck on onCreate method. How can i convert that?

Comment: A ListFragment is a Fragment and contains code for the ListView which you need to write otherwise. You should use onCreateView() instead of onCreate(). Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for understanding the Fragment Lifecycle. If you find the answer useful, please accept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you again for quick response, i have tried that but not getting any output. Here is my code :   @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
         MyPinnedSectionListAdapter adapter = new MyPinnedSectionListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, prepareItems());
         setListAdapter(adapter);
   
       return v;
     }
private void setListAdapter(MyPinnedSectionListAdapter adapter) {
 }